# How to get the data from Sqlite database

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

i'm a new android developer i want get the data from sqlite database from three tables such as ItemMaster,ItemGroupMaster,SalesDetail

**ItemMaster** [image]
**ItemGroupMaster**

[image]

**SalesDetails** [image]

After using this query : **select sd.salesDate,igm.groupName,im.itemName,im.itemprice from salesdetails sd inner join itemmaster im on sd.itemId=im.itemId inner join itemgroupmaster igm on im.groupId=igm.groupId**

**Result**

[image]

Now i want get actual result is look like below image [image]

Please help me 
Thanks in advance

Comment: i know that but i want get data like last image in sqlite

Comment: Replace the pictures by a [mcve] in text form please. Easily done by doing a `.dump` from SQLite command line tool for a suitably tailored toy database. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: have you considered using a json file to transfer it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. The `Qty` and `NetAmount` columns are both aggregates, and `NetAmount` relies on `Qty`, so I used a couple of nested queries:

```
SELECT Y.salesDate
    , Y.GroupName
    , Y.ItemName
    , Y.Qty
    , Y.Price
    , Y.Price * Y.Qty AS NetAmount

FROM

    (SELECT X.salesDate
        , X.groupName AS GroupName
        , X.itemName AS ItemName
        , X.itemprice AS Price
        , COUNT(*) AS Qty 

    FROM

        (SELECT sd.salesDate
            ,igm.groupName
            ,im.itemName
            ,im.itemprice
        FROM salesdetails sd
        INNER JOIN itemmaster im 
            ON sd.itemId = im.itemId
        INNER JOIN itemgroupmaster igm 
            ON im.groupId = igm.groupId
        ) X

    GROUP BY 1,2,3
    ) Y

GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: here what is meaning of GROUP BY 1,2,3 and those GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4,5 please can you explain it

Comment: how to use fromDate and toDate to get the above record

Comment: The numbers in the GROUP BY and ORDER BY refer to the columns in the SELECT statement. So you could also write GROUP BY Y.salesDate, Y.GroupName, Y.ItemName, etc. but it's just simpler to use the numbers for me. Column names are more explicit, in case you plan on changing the order of the columns.